# add picture to json?

Tags: ios, json, swift, jpeg

This is a snipped of the json file i am using

```
 {
"id" : 12252013,
"name" : "Lassy",
"breed" : "Cocker Spaniel",
"photo_large" : 
"http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/puppies/spaniel.jpeg",
"price" : 39999
},
```

I want to use a local png like this but it is resulting in a blank picture.

```
{
"id" : 12252012,
"name" : "Penny",
"breed" : "Dachshund",
"photo_large" : "ready.jpg",
"cuddle_factor" : 5,
"price" : 29999
},
```

[image]

How can I get it to show like the picture below which uses a specifically hosted path for a jpeg?

[image]

I've tried using a image hosted on the web but haven't been able to find the right one quite yet.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In json objects you can provide the file path like that
"photo_large" :"file:///XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXX/filename"
You can convert file path to URI and use it. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the local case

> "photo_large" : "ready.jpg"

you need to use

```
let res = try? JSONDecodable().decode(Root.self,from:data) 
let image = UIImage(named:res.photoLarge)

struct Root : Codable {
   let id: Int
   let name, breed, photoLarge: String
   let cuddleFactor, price: Int

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name, breed
    case photoLarge = "photo_large"
    case cuddleFactor = "cuddle_factor"
    case price
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea to add a picture data itself into json. Put some URL of the image in the json and use it. If you have to send the image in a web service, use multipart format to upload the image along with other info.

From your question, as you want to show the image, you can use CacheManager along with DownloadManager to get the image and show it.